# Swift - design to only parse Json once (currently same data gets parsed for every user selection)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm Learning Swift development for IOS and encountered a design problem in my simple Project. I have a pickerView set up so that everytime user selects a value, different information from the Json is displayed and it works just fine.

However, in my current design the data gets parsed/fetched again everytime the user selects a new value from the pickerview, what I want to do is to collect the data once and then just loop through the same data based on the users selection. My guess is that i need to separate the function to load the data and the function/code to actually do the looping and populate the labels. But I can't seem to find any way to solve it, when i try to return something from my loadData function I get problems with the returns already used inside the closure statements inside the function.

Hopefully you guys understand my question!

The selectedName variable equals the users selected value from the pickerView. 
The function loadData gets run inside the pickerView "didselectrow" function.

```
func loadData() {
    let jsonUrlString = "Here I have my Json URL"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do { let myPlayerInfos = try
            JSONDecoder().decode(Stats.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for item in myPlayerInfos.elements! {
                    if item.web_name == self.selectedName{
                        self.nameLabel.text = "Name:\t \t \(item.first_name!) \(item.second_name!)"     
                    } else {}
                }
            }  
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}//end function loaddata
```

And for reference, the Stats struct:

```
struct Stats: Decodable {
    let phases: [playerPhases]?
    let elements: [playerElements]?
}

struct playerPhases: Decodable{
    let id: Int?
}

struct playerElements: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let photo: String?
    let first_name: String?
    let second_name: String?  
}
```